# Google App Engine Drive API Read a file content(return undefined)

Tags: javascript, google-drive-api

I want read a file content but webContentLink is turning undefined.But other values are coming true. I don't understand.This my code part:

```
function handleAuthClick(event) {
    var options = {
        client_id: CLIENT_ID,
        scope: SCOPES,
        immediate: false
    };
    gapi.auth.authorize(options, handleAuthResult);
    return false;
}

function makeApiCall() {  
    gapi.client.load('drive', 'v2', makeRequest);   
}

function makeRequest() {
    var request = gapi.client.drive.files.list({'q': "title contains '--'"});
    request.execute(function(resp) {

        for (i=0; i<resp.items.length; i++) {
            alert(resp.items[i].webContentLink);//problem is here turning undefined
            var titulo = resp.items[i].title;
            var fechaUpd = resp.items[i].modifiedDate;
            var userUpd = resp.items[i].lastModifyingUserName;
            var userEmbed = resp.items[i].embedLink;
            var userAltLink = resp.items[i].alternateLink;
            var fileInfo = document.createElement('li');
            fileInfo.appendChild(document.createTextNode('TITLE: ' + titulo + ' - LAST MODIF: ' + fechaUpd + ' - BY: ' + userUpd ));                
            document.getElementById('content').appendChild(fileInfo);
        }
    });    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

it works with html file! Webcontentlink is not work with text files.